# how to make spaces between numbers in a string with a batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, count

So i was making a batch file recently, and i made a string. Later i needed to make spaces between the numbers in the string (its hard to describe!).

For example:
The string is `2023`, i want to change the string, and make into `2 0 2 3`

I tried to browse the web but the only thing i found out was that its probably something like this:
`set %string%=%string:"something here"%`

But im not sure what to write there then...

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested:

```
@echo off

set "some_string_with_digits=abc1234fgh098jkl"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0) do (
  set "some_string_with_digits=!some_string_with_digits:%%a=%%a !"
)
echo %some_string_with_digits%
```